# I used 2 different selectors to float an element expecting to get the same result, but i got different result

Tags: html, css

I used 2 different selectors to float an element expecting to get the same result, but i got different results. I don't know what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
/* I used this selector and floated it to the right */
 div > p{
 background-color: #A52A2A;
  float: right;



/* Then i used this selector, and i got a different result*/
#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  float: right;


<div>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  <p id="p3"></p>
  <p id="p4"></p>
  [the first result][1]
```

[the first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpFTH.png)

Comment: there is a difference between floating ONE element and floating ALL of them

Comment: In div > p you are floating all to the right but in #p1 you are floating only a single p.

Comment: I thought writing div > p means i am targeting the first child element

Comment: I just understood child selector better. Thanks a lot!